# react checksum was invalid : client screen height property not applicable on server side

Tags: reactjs

I post again about it and ask if there is a solution to skip following react exception in some cases:

> Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: You're trying to render a
>   component to the document using server rendering but the checksum was
>   invalid. This usually means you rendered a different component type or
>   props on the client from the one on the server, or your render()
>   methods are impure. React cannot handle this case due to cross-browser
>   quirks by rendering at the document root. You should look for
>   environment dependent code in your components and ensure the props are
>   the same client and server side.

I understand react tries to keep integrity but for that kind of scenario it makes no real sense.

my component renders itself with client context and screen resolution, and server rendering is made with ExpressJS.

here an extract of simple ui component called 'App':

```
getDefaultProps: function() {
   // here is size by default
   return {
      size: 500
    }
  },
render: function() {
    return (
      <div><myComponent size={this.props.size} /></div>
    );
}
```

On client side, something like:

```
var height = // jquery stuff to get client screen height
//var height = 500; // in this case works as both client/server size are equal
React.render(App({size:height}), document);
```

On server side, something like:

```
var markup = React.renderToString(APP());
res.send(markup);
```

Any ideas to avoid that annoying exception will be welcome.

Thanks

Julien

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option might be to have the same hard coded height for the server render and the first client render. Then use `componentDidMount` to calculate the real height, and re-render the component with the real height.

Something like:

```
var = App React.createClass({
  getInitialState() {
    return {
      height: 500
    };
  },
  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({height: $(window).height()});
  },
  render() {
    return <MyComponent height={this.state.height} />;
  }
});

React.render(<App />, document);
```

You might want to do that anyway, since you probably want to listen to window resize events and pass a new height.

Comment: Note that the server will never run the `componentDidMount` lifecycle, that is why this would work

Comment: Perfect answer as usual and it was written in documentation about react lifecycle "If you need to interact with the browser, perform your work in componentDidMount()". Thanks again

Comment: Just trying to figure out what this solves, is it to avoid the warning message? Because the warning message is just informing you that because the markup doesn't match it needs to do a re-render, and by doing the re-render in `componentDidMount` instead you're still doing a re-render, so I don't think you are actually getting any performance wins apart from stopping the message showing up?